# Rails (5.2.0) reCaptcha Devise (4.4.3) undefined method users_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, recaptcha

Got an error on tests. Development and production shows no error.

```
Error:
UsersTest#test_creating_a_user:
NoMethodError: undefined method `users_url' for #<RegistrationsController:0x00007fd3e69d1a18>
Did you mean?  user_session_url
Did you mean?  user_session_url
    app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:11:in `check_captcha'
```

Got a devise registration controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   prepend_before_action :check_captcha, only: [:create]

   private

def check_captcha
  unless verify_recaptcha
    self.resource = resource_class.new sign_up_params
    resource.validate # Look for any other validation errors besides Recaptcha
    set_minimum_password_length
    respond_with resource
    # self.resource = resource_class.new sign_up_params
    # respond_with_navigational(resource) { render :new }
  end 
end

def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for resource
  new_user_session_path
end
end
```

Routing

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, only: :omniauth_callbacks, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks'}
```

scope '(:locale)', :locale => /en|ru/ do

```
root :to => 'index#index'

devise_for :users, :controllers => {
                    :registrations => 'registrations',
                    :invitations => 'invitations'
                   },
                   :path => 'auth',
                   :path_names => {
                     :sign_in => 'login',
                     :sign_out => 'logout',
                     :password => 'secret',
                     :confirmation => 'verification',
                     :unlock => 'unblock',
                     :registration => 'register',
                     :sign_up => 'cmon_let_me_in'
                   }, 
                   skip: :omniauth_callbacks

   end
```

Resource passed to `respond_with resource` is valid. 
What's that?!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now bypassing it like that

```
def check_captcha
  return true if Rails.env.test?
  unless verify_recaptcha
    self.resource = resource_class.new sign_up_params
    resource.validate # Look for any other validation errors besides Recaptcha
    set_minimum_password_length
    respond_with resource
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think because of your views.

checkout your views "/devise/registrations/new.html.erb" and make sure you put `<%= recaptcha_tags %>` on sign up button [/devise/registrations/new.html.erb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6hS4.png)

And here is my simple routes:
[routes.rb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yazgY.png)

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when resource is valid itself, but captcha didn't pass. Devise thinks that model is persisted (but it has been validated only) and tries to redirect to it.

Solution is to replace `respond_with resource` to `render :new` in `check_captcha` method.

Answer (score 0):

also does not work without recaptcha, check devise docs to get it working standalone first

Comment: it's written with official docs examples. now I see that method verify_recaptcha  returns differrent values called as test:system and just as test
as for standalone mode looks like there are some rails trobles fixed lately and not released